Minimum distances between plumbing, electrical wiring and/or HVAC elements within a waffle slab?
we are trying to route electrical, plumbing (hot/cold/black/sprinklers), and HVAC ducts in a waffle slab ceiling, and was wondering if there's any code requirement that dictates how far those elements have to be distanced away from each other?
The project location is residential in LA, California.

I think there might be something about hot/heat and electrical/plumbing.  You do not want plastic close to heat.  It seems common sense might be better to go by than by code and/or local regulations.  Have seen some code okay, but common sense says not okay.
